# NavigationLink binding issue

Tags: swift, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm 100% brand new to not just Swift but development. I've been through a few books and I'm starting to get it, but I'm probably making some dumb mistake.

The problem is I have a list displaying sets of Measurements() and I'm trying to get a NavigationLink so when a touch happens, the EditMeasurementView opens. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is EditMeasurementView:

```
struct EditMeasurementView: View {
    @Binding var measurements: Measurements

    var body: some View {
        Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
}

struct EditMeasurementView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
      //EditChecklistItemView(checklistItem: .constant(ChecklistItem(name: "Sample item")))
          EditMeasurementView(measurements:  .constant(Measurements()))
    }
}
```

Here is ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var measurements = Measurements()
    @State var newMeasurementViewIsVisible = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(measurements.items) { MeasurementItem in
                    NavigationLink(destination: EditMeasurementView(measurements: $measurements)) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("\(MeasurementItem.mdate)")
                            Spacer()
                            Text("\(MeasurementItem.weight)" + " lbs")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: measurements.deleteListItem)
                .onMove(perform: measurements.moveListItem)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Measurements", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading: Button(action: { self.newMeasurementViewIsVisible = true
                  }) {
                    HStack {
                      Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                      Text("New")
                    }
                  },
                  trailing: EditButton()
            )
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $newMeasurementViewIsVisible) {
            NewMeasurementItemView(measurements: self.measurements)
        }
    }
} 


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The error swift is throwing is:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'ObservedObject<Measurements>.Wrapper' to
expected argument type 'Binding<Measurements>'" on the NavigationLink
line in ContentView.
```

Comment: What is `EditMeasurementView` used for? Is it to edit an single measurement item in the List?

Comment: Correct. Another list eventually to edit the values of a single measurement item.

Comment: Ok, I think I may have a solution for what you want. But what do you want to actually do with `EditMeasurementView`? Remove an element from the list, or change it for example?

Comment: I want to be able to modify existing values here, i.e. correcting a typo when a new item was added previously.

Comment: I'm not too sure, sorry! Hopefully someone else can answer this :)

Comment: @George_E FYI - I figured it out if you look at my edit. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Remove it from your question, and add it as answer

Answer (score 0):

/// Figured it out! ///

In the EditMeasurementView I was binding to the wrong object. I should have been binding to MeasurementItem instead of Measurements. Measurements is the array containing MeasurementItems, but here I'm only editing a single set of MeasurementItems.